# Can't change ionic app's version code

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play

I'm facing a very frustrating issue.
I can't update my app's version number or code.
Every time I build the app, the config.xml is reset and with it also the version so it stays at version 0.0.1.
This makes it impossible to update my app in the Google Play store.

I have updated my ionic and cordova to the latest versions.

Has anyone else had this issue? And does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: What is the location of the *config.xml* in which you are updating the app's version. Is it *your_project/config.xml*?

Answer (score 0):

In  **build.gradle(Module :app)**  you have to increase the **version code** by 1 and change **versionName** accordingly.